# Virtuemart class 'JDispatcher' not found error when upgrade Joomla 3 to Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, virtuemart, upgrade

I'm using Virtuemart 3 and Joomla 3, after upgrarding to VM 4 and Joomla 4, it say error `Class 'JDispatcher' not found` from `JROOT/plugins/vmshipment/rules_shipping_advanced/rules_shipping_framework_joomla.php:39`

This is the error causing code part:

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('vmshipmentrules');
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
$defs = $dispatcher->trigger('onVmShippingRulesRegisterCustomFunctions',array());
```

I have done many search on google but no result, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, it works.

```
use Joomla\Event\Dispatcher as EventDispatcher;
$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
$defs = $dispatcher->triggerEvent('onVmShippingRulesRegisterCustomFunctions',array());
```